# Windows 10 IoT - Supported bindings

Tags: wcf, windows-10, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

According to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel

the Windows Universal Platform supports the NetHttpBinding. In Visual Studio, I can develop a simple WCF client using this binding, without errors. I can use the NetHttpBinding class of the ServerModel namespace. When I deploy the client to a Raspberry Pi 2, a

> PlatformNotSupportedException

occurs.

Which WCF bindings are really supported by Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: What are you trying to call? WCF isn't the best option for IoT (there's even a UserVoice suggestion to replace NetTcpBinding with AMQP - by Clemens Vasters himself). A REST call is best for simple calls, AMQP better for guaranteed and/or queued delivery, authentication etc. AMQP is a *very* safe bet as Azure already supports

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no information available public about WCF client profile for windows 10 IoT, but I think it's very easily for you to test them. It's still a prerelease preview, so it's really possible.

To move forward, I think you can use HttpClient in System.Net.Http namespace to consume restful service. check [Jeff Sanders's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/05/how-to-use-httpclient-to-post-json-data.aspx).