# Connect to a wcf with windows 10 iot

Tags: c#, wcf, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to connect a windows 10 iot app (uwp) to a simple wcf service library.

But I always have the same problem: it appears that on my .NETcore.UniversalWindowsPlateform (5.0.0), I have an exeption

> PlateformNotSupported

Here is the simple code to connect to the wcf:

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private InstanceContext instanceContext;
    private Service1Client serviceProxy;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);

        serviceProxy = new Service1Client();
    }
}
```

For me, it looks like UpnEndpoint is not implemented yet on my version of .NETcore

Did someone succeed connecting to a wcf with windows 10 iot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151110/windows-10-iot-supported-bindings

Comment: I saw that post but he is not really helping me...

Comment: Not all bindings are supported for all platforms. I get the same exception if, for instance, i use a duplex `NetTcpBinding` with a regular UWP app (not even IoT).

Comment: I hope this problem will be solved soon, here is the release note for the RC2 : https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v1.0.0-rc2.md   But i don't know when it will be released

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved with the new version of wcf. There is no "PlateformNotSupported" Anymore